# Custom Close, Maximize and Maximize buttons doesn´t work after build in MacOS

Tags: javascript, html, electron, electron-builder

I have created custom header buttons for Minimize and close window that work fine when runing local but after creating build and install on MacOS, buttons stop working.

**Renderer.html**

```html
<div class="toggle-icon">
    <svg class="minimizeicon" onclick="minimize()" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-dash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M4 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7A.5.5 0 0 1 4 8z" />
    </svg>
    <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="10"
        height="15"
        fill="currentColor"
        class="bi bi-dash restoreDown"
        viewBox="0 0 512 512">
        <path d="M432 48H208c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32V96H128V80c0-44.2 35.8-80 80-80H432c44.2 0 80 35.8 80 80V304c0 44.2-35.8 80-80 80H416V336h16c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32V80c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32zM48 448c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16H320c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V256H48V448zM64 128H320c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64V448c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64H64c-35.3 0-64-28.7-64-64V192c0-35.3 28.7-64 64-64z"/>
    </svg>
    
    <svg
        class="closeicon"
        onclick="windowClose()"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="16"
        height="16"
        fill="currentColor"
        class="bi bi-x"
        viewBox="0 0 16 16" >
        <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

**Renderer.js**

```js
function minimize() {
    console.log("Hello");
    ipcRenderer.send("minimize");
}

// To close window
function windowClose() {
    ipcRenderer.send("close");
}
```

**Main.js**

```js
var win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 400,
    height: 620,
    frame: false, // Remove the default window frame
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    resizable: false,
    center: true,
    fullscreen: false,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
        enableRemoteModule: true,
        powerMonitor: true,
        backgroundThrottling: false
    },
    //icon: __dirname+"/assets/Icons/win/icon.ico",
    title: "Redmine Flux Time Tracker",
    
});

ipcMain.on("minimize", (event, data) => {
    win.minimize();
});

ipcMain.on("close", (event) => {
    win.close();
});
```

Using IPC in Window it work fine in MacOS also work fine but after installing buttons stop working.

Comment: `enableRemoteModule: true,` shouldn't work in current electron. Are you on an old version of Hyperdrive? Consider upgrading to latest stable and trying again

Comment: @pushkin  electron version-  "electron": "^22.0.3"